# Target Specific Product when calling woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woothemes

I am trying to change the add to cart functionality on the product archive/shop page on woocommerce based on a custom field using woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item. However if only even one item with the custom field exists on the page the code will effect all products even the ones without the custom field. And I completely understand why this is happening. My question is, is there any way to only apply the action to that one specific product.

```
/*STEP 1 - REMOVE ADD TO CART BUTTON ON PRODUCT ARCHIVE (SHOP) */

function remove_loop_button(){

 global $product;
 $mycustomfield = get_post_meta($product->id, 'my_custom_field', true);

 if($mycustomfield == true)
 {
  remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item',
 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
 }

}
add_action('init','remove_loop_button');



/*STEP 2 -ADD NEW BUTTON THAT LINKS TO PRODUCT PAGE FOR EACH PRODUCT */

add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item','replace_add_to_cart');
function replace_add_to_cart() {

 global $product;
 $mycustomfield = get_post_meta($product->id, 'my_custom_field', true);

 if($mycustomfield == true)
 {
   $link = $product->get_permalink();
   echo do_shortcode('<a href="'.$link.'" class="button addtocartbutton">View Product</a>');
 }

}
```

Comment: is `$post->my_custom_field` a new way of getting the custom field? sorry... just thinking this is wrong or you have your own implementation?

Comment: No that was me just being lazy when asking the question.  How I grab the post meta is    $myfield = get_post_meta($product->id, 'my_field', true);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need to remove the `woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart` hook.
Instead, use `woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link` filter. This filter contains the html button link "add to cart"... which means you can replace this with your html for your button...

```
add_filter('woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link','replace_add_to_cart', 10, 2);
function replace_add_to_cart( $add_to_cart_link, $product ) {

 $buyback = get_post_meta($product->id, 'is_buyback', true);
 if($buyback == true)
 {
   $link = $product->get_permalink();
   $add_to_cart_link = do_shortcode('<a href="'.$link.'" class="button addtocartbutton">View Product</a>');
 }
 return $add_to_cart_link;
}
```

update based on comments below...

> Do you know how to do this for a single product page ?

you have to remove the button's hook in `woocommerce_init`.

```
add_action('woocommerce_init', 'remove_woocommerce_template_hooks');
function remove_woocommerce_template_hooks(){
    global $product;
    $buyback = get_post_meta($product->id, 'is_buyback', true);
    if($buyback == true) {
        //remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_simple_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_simple_add_to_cart', 30 );
        //remove_action( 'woocommerce_grouped_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_grouped_add_to_cart', 30 );
        //remove_action( 'woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart', 30 );
        //remove_action( 'woocommerce_external_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_external_add_to_cart', 30 );
        //remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'woocommerce_single_variation', 10 );
        //remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'woocommerce_single_variation_add_to_cart_button', 20 );
    }
}
```

I choose to remove `woocommerce_simple_add_to_cart` for simple product just for example...
then add a hook...

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_simple_add_to_cart', 'my_woocommerce_simple_add_to_cart', 30 );
//add_action( 'woocommerce_grouped_add_to_cart', 'my_woocommerce_simple_add_to_cart', 30 );
function my_woocommerce_simple_add_to_cart(){
    global $product;
    $buyback = get_post_meta($product->id, 'is_buyback', true);
    if($buyback == true) {
       $link = $product->get_permalink();
       echo do_shortcode('<a href="'.$link.'" class="button addtocartbutton">View Product</a>');
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you Reigel. This is the correct answer for replacing the button on the archive/shop page. And you are also correct about the if statement. I have updated the if statement in the question.

Comment: Do you know how to do this for a single product page ?

Comment: I updated the code... play around if something is missing... I have not tested it...